# Showing title once from inside an each loop

Tags: jquery, loops, each

Im trying to show just one title

```
s ='<div class="title ' + summaryClass +'">' + summary + '</div>';
```

from inside an each loop but it shows everytime it loops, as you can guess im new to this lol

```
        $.each(data.items, function(e, item) {
      var starting = item.start.dateTime || item.start.date ||'';
      var end = item.end.dateTime || item.end.date ||'';
      var summary = item.summary || '';
      var description = item.description;
      var location = item.location;
      var theDay = item.start.dateTime || item.start.date ||'';



      var summaryClass = summary.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,"-");


      s ='<div class="title ' + summaryClass +'">' + summary + '</div>';
      /*s +='<div class="day">'+ formatDate(theDay, defaults.dateFormating.trim()) + '</div>';*/

      s +='<div class="time">'+ formatDate(starting, defaults.dateFormat.trim()) +' - '+ formatDate(end, defaults.dateFormat.trim()) +'</div>';
      s +='<div class="time"></div>';


      if(description) {
        s +='<div class="description">'+ description + '</div>';
      }

      if(location) {
        s +='<div class="location">Location: ' + location + '</div>';
      }


      if(formatDate(theDay, defaults.dateFormating.trim()) == "Saturday") {
         $($div).append('<li class="' + formatDate(theDay, defaults.dateFormating.trim()) + '">' + s + '</li>');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you just want to show the title once.

So why aren't you setting a variable for checking if you already have shown the title?

e.g. var titleShown = false

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cwz1a87b/2/) is a little example of what I am talking about.

```
var titleShown = false;
$.each(_array, function(e,item){
if(!titleShown)
  {
    result += "Title: " + item.title + "; ";
    titleShown= true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code just check this.Im checking whether tag(id) exist or not. first iteration it will be null and once tag is executed, second iteration it will be existing so it will skip the tag.

```
 $.each(data.items, function(e, item) {
      var starting = item.start.dateTime || item.start.date ||'';
      var end = item.end.dateTime || item.end.date ||'';
      var summary = item.summary || '';
      var description = item.description;
      var location = item.location;
      var theDay = item.start.dateTime || item.start.date ||'';



      var summaryClass = summary.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,"-");

if(document.getElementById("check_once") == null){
      s ='<div id="check_once" class="title ' + summaryClass +'">' + summary + '</div>';
}
      /*s +='<div class="day">'+ formatDate(theDay, defaults.dateFormating.trim()) + '</div>';*/

      s +='<div class="time">'+ formatDate(starting, defaults.dateFormat.trim()) +' - '+ formatDate(end, defaults.dateFormat.trim()) +'</div>';
      s +='<div class="time"></div>';


      if(description) {
        s +='<div class="description">'+ description + '</div>';
      }

      if(location) {
        s +='<div class="location">Location: ' + location + '</div>';
      }


      if(formatDate(theDay, defaults.dateFormating.trim()) == "Saturday") {
         $($div).append('<li class="' + formatDate(theDay, defaults.dateFormating.trim()) + '">' + s + '</li>');
      }
    })
```